# Calculating the Riemann sum $\lim_{n \to \infty} { \sum_{k=1}^{n} { (\frac{nk-1}{n^3})\sin(\frac{k}{n}) } }$

Tags: calculus

We need to calculate this:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} { \sum_{k=1}^{n} { (\frac{nk-1}{n^3})\sin(\frac{k}{n}) }       }$$

So I know this is Riemann sum.
This is what I started doing:

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} { (\frac{nk-1}{n^3})\sin(\frac{k}{n})}  = \sum_{k=1}^{n} { (\frac{k}{n^2 } - \frac{1}{n^3})\sin(\frac{k}{n})}$$

But then I noticed that we can not get $\frac{1}{n}$ outside. How do we exactly know what is the partition?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The last expression equals: $\sum_1^n \dfrac{k}{n^2} \sin \dfrac{k}{n}- \sum_1^n \dfrac{1}{n^3}\sin \dfrac{k}{n}$, now what is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n^3} \sum_1^n \sin \dfrac{k}{n}$? And use Riemann tranformation on $\sum_1^n \dfrac{k}{n^2} \sin \dfrac{k}{n}$.

Use this : $\int_0^1 f(x) =\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{1}{n} \sum_1^n f(x)$

Comment: I see.But what exactly is "Reimann Transformation"?

Comment: @Notme: I have added it. Do you recognize it?

Comment: And hey, I noticed that there's something I don't understand. I usually calculate reimman when outside we have $\frac{1}{n}$ but here we have $\frac{1}{n^3}$. What difference does it make exactly?

Comment: That's why I split the function into two parts, notice that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n^3} \sum_1^n \sin \dfrac{k}{n}=0$, So, it is just evaluating $\sum_1^n \dfrac{k}{n^2} \sin \dfrac{k}{n}$.

Comment: You have skipped me by a step. I know the integral way of calculating a reimans some, but yet again, only when there's $\frac{1}{n}$ outside. Here we have a different thing: $\frac{1}{n^3}$. If you can explain to me the difference I will appreciate it.

Comment: Where do we have $\dfrac{1}{n^3}$? The term with $\dfrac{1}{n^3}$ gets cancelled, it tends to be $0$.

Comment: If you had $\frac{1}{n^3}(SUM)$ then its the same as $\frac{1}{n^2} \frac{1}{n}(SUM)$ and in the limit its $0 \cdot (\mbox{whatever the sum converged to})$